# MYSQL - Select count of all rows that are duplicates in 1 column and distinct in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, distinct

I have a MYSQL table called `transactions.addresses` which contains a `username` and `address` column. When a user creates a transaction on my website, it is logged in my database as shows below

```
|username|    address   |
--------------------------
| jeremy | a33bfd019    |
| jeremy | b583ffs9a    |
| ben    | c09123jca    |
```

How do I run a query that will show a count of all `address` fields that are found more than once in the table **and** have more than 1 different username associated with them in the database? In other words, I want to see how many different users have used the same address value in their transactions. Using the below dataset as an example:

```
|username|    address   |
--------------------------
| jeremy | a33bfd019    |
| jeremy | b583ffs9a    |
| jeremy | b583ffs9a    |
| ben    | c09123jca    |
| ben    | b583ffs9a    |
```

I would expect to see a result as follows:

```
|address   | count  |
--------------------------
| b583ffs9a| 2      |
| c09123jca| 1      |
| a33bfd019| 1      |
```

the address `b583ffs9a` should have a count of 2 because 2 users have used this address.

Comment: Hint: `COUNT(DISTINCT username)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by Barmar, you can just aggregate by `address` and count distinct `username`s in each group:

```
select address, count(distinct username) no_usernames
from mytable
group by address
```